# Where is the "repair" folder located in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

By repair folder I mean the folder that contains a copy of `system`, `sam`, `security` and others located on `[X]:\Windows\config`.

Comment: back in 7 the Registry backup was located in C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack (c being the system disk here). It always helps to describe what your trying to DO in the question, then a answer could possibly be more complete for your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the folder with the backup data:

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack
```

Comment: It would be useful to know how to get this data back from \ RegBack.

Comment: @Yurij73 simply copy them to the CONFIG folder.